# Using sqldf & RPostgrSQL in opencpu app

Tags: r, opencpu

I'm creating a very simple sqldf app where I want to query postgresql database and return results.  Here is my R code:

```
getproperties <- function(name="") {
  options(sqldf.RPostgreSQL.user ="user", 
      sqldf.RPostgreSQL.password ="password",
      sqldf.RPostgreSQL.dbname ="db",
      sqldf.RPostgreSQL.host ="server", 
      sqldf.RPostgreSQL.port =5432,
      sqldf.driver = "PostgreSQL")
  property <- sqldf("select name, url from aston_hotels.property")
  return(property)
}
```

When I call this using OpenCpu

```
curl http://localhost/ocpu/user/kesav/library/mylib/getproperties/json --data name=kk
```

I get the following error

```
R call failed: process died.
```

Don't know what's I'm doing wrong.  Can anyone point me to an example on how to use DBI from OpenCpu?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the function works when running it on the same machine the terminal but not within OpenCPU, it is likely a security problem. Please check in `/var/log/kern.log` if there are any lines printed containing `DENIED` when using the application.

If this is the case, you can add the appropriate privileges the the security profile by editing

```
/etc/apparmor.d/opencpu.d/custom
```

Also see the [server manual](http://jeroenooms.github.com/opencpu-manual/opencpu-server.pdf) section titled *Customizing the security profile* on this topic.